# Determining cause of death from Spanish death certificate

Tags: palaeography, cause-of-death, spain

This is related to:

- [Deciphering names from Spanish death certificate](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/16163/8882)
- [Deciphering Work Profession from Spanish death certificate](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/16165/8882)

I am trying to decipher this cause of death. The added complication is that it is written in Spanish:

[image: Cause of Death]

These are the phrases that I do know:

- **ayer** -> yesterday
- **cuatro horas** -> four hours (I don't know if that is AM or PM)
- **certificado medico** -> medical certificate
- **este cuidad** -> this city

Excluding accents this is what I have:

> fallecio en **su domicilio** el dia de **ayer** a las **cuatro horas** y - minutos, a consecuencia de **coma ? ? ?** segun resulta de **certificadio medifico** y reconocimiento practicado, y su cadaver habra de recibir sepultura en el cementerio de **este cuidad**.

In English:

> died at **her home** on the day of **yesterday** at **four hours** and - minutes, as a result of **coma ? ? ?** as it results from the **medical certificate** and recognition practice, and her body will receive a burial in the cemetery of **this city**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm no great shakes at Spanish but fortunately many medical terms derive from the same Latin and Greek roots:

> coma urémico, esclerosis generalizada

Translates to: Uraemic coma, generalized sclerosis

Presumably kidney failure, it is unclear whether the sclerosis was a primary or secondary problem.