# Deciphering names from Spanish death certificate

Tags: palaeography, death-records, spain, transcriptions

This is a follow on from:

- [Determining cause of death from Spanish death certificate](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/16157/8882)
- [Deciphering Work Profession from Spanish death certificate](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/16165/8882)

This is the first part of my Great Great Grandmothers death certificate:

[image: Death Certificate snippet]

I have already discussed this certificate with my mother (who is Spanish) and we have come up with the following translation so far:

> In **the city of Corella**, province of **Navarra**, at **12 noon** on **28th April**
> **1944**, before **D. Santiago [Frances Segura]**, Municipal Judge and D.
> **Pablo [????? ?????]**, Secretary, proceed to register the death of Da.
> **Juana Sanz Cueva**, born in **Corella**, province of **Navarra**, on **6th May
> 1857** (86 years old), daughter of D. **Blas Sanz** and Da. **Felipa Cueva**,
> resided at the street, of **[????? ?????]**, number 40, of profession
> **[????? ?????]** and state **[?????]** of D. **Ciriaco Bienzobas** **[????? ?????**
> **????? ?????]** children **[?????]** Leon, Villar, Maria **[?????]** and Felipa.

This was the best we could come up with. We are struggling with some of the names. Ideally I would like to decipher and complete the whole segment but in particular I am interested in the names of Great Great aunts and uncles. I know for sure:

- Maria
- Villar
- Leon
- Felipa

But there are other words and / or names in that segment that I am not sure about.

If anyone knows Spanish and is good at this kind of thing then I welcome your assistance. I included the whole snippet from the certificate so you could see more handwriting.

## Update

Based on the comments I have adjusted the information like this so far:

> In the city of Corella, province of Navarra, at 12 noon on 28th April
> 1944, before D. Santiago [Frances Segura], Municipal Judge and D.
> Pablo [????? ?????], Secretary,  proceed to register the death of Da.
> Juana Sanz Cueva, born in Corella, province of Navarra, on 6th May
> 1857 (86 years old), daughter of D. Blas Sanz and Da. Felipa Cueva,
> resided at  Tajadas Street, number 40, of profession [????? ?????] and
> widow of D. Ciriaco Bienzobas of which marriage are left five
> children [?????], Leon, Villar, Maria [?????] and Felipa.

---

### Off Topic

I just received a certificate from Corella today for her birth in 1857! Awesome!

Comment: The "state" is viuda, that is widow.

Comment: There is a Calle Tajadas in Corella.

Comment: It's clearly "cinco hijos", that is 5 children.["Of which marriage are left five children" is my reading.

Comment: Is it Bien Zobas [that is, two separate apellidos]?

Comment: @erstwhileeditor No, it is Bienzobas. This judge has only used the first surnames (with exception of Juana). I know this from gravestones and my living relatives in Spain.

Comment: @erstwhileeditor So for the 5 children, it looks like "xxxxx, Leon, Villar, Maria xxxxx, Felipa".

Comment: @erstwhileeditor on Maria gravestone stone it only says "Maria Bienzobas Sanz"

Comment: I think your “Update” would cut/paste into a useful self-answer.

Comment: The last part reads: "are left five children called/named: Leon, Villar, Maria, Mauricio and Felipa.

Comment: @TrebiaProject. Yeah, the only problem is that no one knows of this "Mauricio". The other 4 are known.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle the script mentions five children and, on the other side, there is no comma separating María and Mauricio. So, either there are 5 children and 2 of them are Maria and Mauricio, or the registry has an error and there are 4 children and "Maria Mauricio" is one of them. Do you have evidences about the woman actual name? I have seen this kind of error before.

Comment: @TrebiaProject.At the moment I don't have evidences about them. Only Villar who is my Great Grandmother and Juana my Great Great Grandmother. It is tricky getting hold of all the certificates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I count correctly, there are five missing blocks:

> In the city of Corella, province of Navarra, at 12 noon on 28th April 1944, before D. Santiago [Frances Segura], Municipal Judge and D. Pablo [????? ?????], Secretary,  proceed to register the death of Da. Juana Sanz Cueva, born in Corella, province of Navarra, on 6th May 1857 (86 years old), daughter of D. Blas Sanz and Da. Felipa Cueva, resided at  Tajadas Street, number 40, of profession [????? ?????] and widow of D. Ciriaco Bienzobas of which marriage are left five children [?????], Leon, Villar, Maria [?????] and Felipa.

I would go for:

- D. Pablo Salvatierra ¿Lasa?
- profesión *sus labores* (housewife)
- are left five children *llamados* (called)
- María Mauricia

Comment: Thanks. If that word is llamados (called) then there are only 4 names and not 5. So the word can't be cinco

Comment: @AndrewTruckle maybe they missed the comma between _María_ and the following, which may then be _Mauricio_ (a man). It would make quite a lot of sense, since having composed names on just one of them sounds strange

Comment: OK, the only problem s that at the moment no one knows this Mauricio.

Comment: I like "llamados". I don't think it is odd to specify Maria X. I am not sure exactly how Spanish punctuation of lists goes - the comma after llamados would surely be odd? I wonder if the registrar made a mistake either miscounting (wrote cinco, meant cuatro) or omitting a name?

Comment: @erstwhileeditor agreed, the comma after _llamados_ is very odd, totally against Spanish punctuation rules. Could it be some dirt on the paper or a wanna-be accent in the _y_ (which would be incorrect)?

Comment: I can imagine this conversation: Registrar, "How many siblings did Dna Felipa have?"   Informant "There were four of them"[meaning family of 4]. Registrar adds Felipa and writes "cinco". Registrar "Names?" and then doesn't notice the inconsistency. Perhaps I am too imaginative.

Comment: OK, for now we will assume Maria Mauricia and 4 in total.

Answer (score 3):

María's name may be **María Mauricia** (as in the Spanish Habsburg princess).

Answer (score 3):

In the city of Corella, province of Navarra, at 12 noon on 28th April 1944, before D. Santiago Frances Segura, Municipal Judge and D. Pablo Salvatierra Lara, Secretary, proceed to register the death of Da. Juana Sanz Cueva, born in Corella, province of Navarra, on 6th May 1857 (86 years old), daughter of D. Blas Sanz and Da. Felipa Cueva, resided at Tajadas Street, number 40, of profession housewife, marital status widow of D. Ciriaco Bienzobas of which marriage are left five children named León, Villar, Maria, Mauricio and Felipa.