# Deciphering some text on a Spanish Birth Certificate

Tags: birth-records, palaeography, spain, 1850s

Yesterday I received the Birth Certificate for my Great x2 Grandmother. She was born on 6th May, 1857in Corella:

[image]

I know that her name was **Juana Sanz Cueva** because we have already discussed her [Death Certificate](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/16163/deciphering-names-from-spanish-death-certificate). What's more, we can see her parents listed on this birth certificate:

- Blas Sanz
- Felipa Cueva

Whilst I am struggling to read some of the writing (like the street she was born in) I am more curious about her name. At the top of the certificate I see:

> **Corella** Nacimiento de **una nina llamada Juana Sanz ?????**

I can't make out that last word. I assumed it would have said Cueva but clearly not. What is it actually saying?

---

### Side Note

Based on the answer provided about the location I was able to find that street (Barranquillo) On Google Maps in Corella:

[image]

Unfortunately it does not support street view mode for that road.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell, the first six lines read as follows (italics indicate handwritten text):

> *Corella* Nacimiento de *una niña llamada Juana Estanislaoa Sanz*
> El día *seis de Mayo de 1857,*
> á la hora de *las seis de la tarde*
> en la calle de*l Barranquillo*
> Número *13.* cuarto
> Es hij*a de legitimo matrim°.*

Estanislaoa (**edit:** actually more probably *Estanislaa*, see comments) is a most unusual name, but seems to have been in use in many Spanish-speaking countries in the 19th century.

Comment: Thank you. It is just weird that this Surname has suddenly dropped in when it is mentioned no where else on the certificate.

Comment: Could it be *Estanislaa" (https://www.popular-babynames.com/name/estanislaa)> It says it is a girls name and it looks like two a's. Could it thus be her secondary "name" and opposed to a surname? And she just never used it in life?

Comment: Yes, it's a second given name, or a middle name if you like, and I agree that it is more likely **Estanislaa**. Creating a female version of a name ending in _-ao_ is awkward and resulted in both Estanislaoa and Estanislaa. The latter is probably considered more correct, but the two consecutive 'a's look odd.