# Deciphering Work Profession from Spanish death certificate

Tags: palaeography, death-records, spain, profession

This is a follow on from:

- [Determining cause of death from Spanish death certificate](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/16157/8882)
- [Deciphering names from Spanish death certificate](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/16163/8882)

This is the first part of my Great Great Grandmothers death certificate:

[image: Death Certificate snippet]

I am trying to determine the **work profession**.

If anyone knows Spanish and is good at this kind of thing then I welcome your assistance. I included the whole snippet from the certificate so you could see more handwriting.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

My reading is "profesión, sus labores". In view of the 1970 film "De profesión, sus labores" I take it this is how one says "housewife/domestic duties" on a Spanish Death certificate.

See also the translation from an [online dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/spanish-english/profesi%C3%B3n-sus-labores):

> profesión: sus labores
>
> (en censo, formulario) occupation: housewife

Comment: I can confirm both that it it reads "sus labores" and that this expression is usual in old documents, even for women that were more or less in the work market. Several decades ago, Spanish women were somehow supposed to be housewifes while Spanish men were supposed to have a profession. Having an official document stating "sus labores" doesn't discard that she made an economic activity that we would describe as a profession. Furthermore, that lady died very old, and they might have reported as a housewife what we would see as a retired worker.